# Creating/Organising a portable C++ library

Tags: c++, linux, portability, bitbucket

I'm not sure the way I'm organising my library is the most elegant way to organise it. I'm mainly concerned about making all the code that I type compile/run for all systems that I'm targeting (keeping it portable), and also keeping it up-to-date for every system.

For example:
I'm not sure using __declspec(dllexport/dllimport) would be used for Mac or Linux. I assume that it's not, but I don't know what the equivalent is for Mac/Linux is. Or another example might be calling specific Operating System functions, which I try to avoid. However, things such as: measuring how long something takes to happen*, in a precise manner, does require me to call OS specific functions.

*as in getting the user's time precisely (down to micro/milli-seconds).

The systems that I am currently (perhaps more in the future) aiming for is Mac, Windows and Linux. But testing that the code compiles (and runs correctly) for every system just seems like a waste of time. As currently, the way I'm proposing to do it, requires me to make a separate project for every system. i.e. I create a Visual Studio Project for Windows, an Xcode project for Mac, and use the command line for Linux or use some other IDE.

Okay, so my main problems with the way I organise things are:
1. Time Consumption, as in creating the projects for all systems and keeping each indiviual project, for each system up-to-date.
2. Knowledge on all IDE's/Compilers that I require to use

Please note, I've never really *used** Linux before, I'm thinking about switching. The only problem that I'm concerned about is finding the right tools for me to use with it, and finding the right Distro that would suit me, for what I need. I would really appreciate if someone that is experienced with Linux could guide me, or give me some advice whether to switch or not.

I really like Visual Studio, and it's been my main IDE for quite a while now. I'm just not sure if I want to ditch Visual Studio or not, for Linux; as I don't know if the tools that are available for Linux can do what Visual Studio can or not. What I mean is, it being as user friendly as Visual Studio is. I'm afraid to learn how to use Linux's tools, I'm just not sure if it's worth doing so. Time isn't a major factor on this library, I have plenty of time, I'm fairly young and determined to program as my career in the future.

*I have used it before, but I've never replaced it for Windows.

I am currently hosting all my source code for my project on BitBucket, but at the moment, I only have the RAW code on my repo. There is no project files or any other tool to compile it with, just the code and a readme file. I was thinking of using Makefiles, since they seem popular. But I've never made a Makefile before, don't get me wrong, I am willing to learn. I'm just not really sure where to start. I've heard that people use CMake to create portable libraries, such as SFML and Ogre3D. I've built a couple of libraries with CMake, but I have no clue on how to actually make my own library with it to make my project/make files. Should I learn and incorporate CMake with my library, or is there a better option available?

**EDIT:**

I'm not aiming to write a library for actual Software that uses a GUI. I'm mainly aimed to write ***games***.

Comment: Mac OS X and Linux can share a single build system, e.g. one based on the GNU autotools. CMake is a good alternative. But I do suggest you learn how to use Linux at a basic level before starting to program for it.

Comment: Resort to portable libraries as much as possible (for example, your timing needs can be satisfied by Boost.Chrono, or maybe `std::chrono`, if your targets compilers support it, but I don't know about VS)

Comment: I'm not concerned about time. To be honest, I would rather experience more than anything. Oh and I already have measuring time implemented in my library, I was just referring to that as an example to make sure that there are no bugs for every system and it compiles correctly. As I can't test it on Windows for Linux/Mac.

Comment: And also... the main reason I want the experience is if I want to create a portable program in the future, and there happens to be no option but to create my own code (which could happen, you never know). I want to be able to know and be experienced in doing exactly that.
Especially considering if I want to do this as a career and I had to do it for a project. I'm currently 16 at the moment, and I want that sort of experience under my belt; after-all I think it's better to know than not know at all.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport/dllimport)` is a Windows-only thing. You can have those as macros that are conditionally set to empty on OSX and Linux.

Comment: Yes, I realise that, I just didn't know what the equivalent was for Mac/Linux, and I assume that you don't either? Unless there is no way to make a dynamic library on Mac/Linux? But I think there is a way to make one... unless I'm mistaken, for Mac at least. Or perhaps you don't need to do define what classes you want to export to the dynamic binary. I'm just more concerned on organisation of my library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Boost. Boost will help your portability more than you can imagine. Its only real sticking point is, believe it or not, OS X.

2 - Use CMake. It integrates with Visual Studio project files as the build tool, and you can put most of your different-platform compilation voodoo in there.

3 - If you're seriously writing a portable library, consider writing it in C/writing a C wrapper, or making it header-only, or providing the source-code. Making it a shared or statically linkable library does not mean that it will play nice. Name mangling leads to inconsistencies that will blow your mind.

4 - Always be explicit about the number of bits in each variable.

5 - use git. It'll allow you to setup a crappy local server for a repository very easy and get very fast transfers of the kind of huge changes MSVC will make annoyingly

There are a lot more best-practices that can be discussed about cross-platform development. All of that advice isn't applicable in every case; I have a very code-heavy Linux/Windows library that I code almost exclusively in MSVC2k10 and mostly build/test for in Linux, and it is nowhere close to header-only.

EDIT in response to comments:

git was suggested because I find it very easy to use and manage locally. I've use svn before and liked it, I won't really endorse any others, but there are probably plenty of fine ones.

To expound on point 3,
A C wrapper would make it so that anyone anywhere could use your library - FORTRAN developers, Ruby, even Java.
Otherwise you generally have to have similar compiler versions to link properly and it will only link to other C++ code, outside the case of DLLs, and there are still versioning issues. It's one of the stupidest problems in C++ left over, check "name mangling" on Wikipedia. There is a reason widely-used libraries are written in C or have C wrappers, such as libz, openssl etc.

There are other advantages to it. Exception propagation across dynamic libraries is non-existent; with static libraries it can be inconsistent or non-existent.

You'll find that the most widely-used C++ libraries are mostly header-only, like Boost. A header-only library solves many problems by putting all the code directly into a project in a relatively intuitive way, and modern compilers can still optimize away much (but certainly not all) of the extra compile time associated with it.

With all this said, it is certainly possible to do without a C wrapper or header-only, it is just annoying and very troublesome. DLL hell and its Linux equivalents still exist.

You also asked about Boost. That depends. If you're distributing the sourcecode then you certainly must distribute Boost with your code/have people install it. Having people install libraries in order to compile other libraries or use programs is common practice. Think of how specific versions of DirectX come with games for an example.

However if you are distributing binary versions of your library, statically linking against Boost will eliminate any need to include it as long as you are careful to keep Boost headers out of the outward-facing parts of your library. This is where you start seeing things like void * pointers inside C++ headers; an unfortunate side-effect of some of the shortcomings of C++ compilation and library distribution unfortunately.

Comment: Do you think it's worth switching to Linux, or should I just stick to Visual Studio? Also... If I were to use boost, then everyone that is willing to use my library would also have to download boost, yes? I doubt someone would actually use my library, but you never know. Boost is such a big library, however it is a good library. 

And... if I were to make a C wrapper, or write it in pure C, how on earth would I implement everything I was going to use boost? I don't think writing it in C may be a good idea for my case, maybe for some parts of my library but not all of it.

Comment: +1 for 1) and 4), even when unsolicited git advertising as in 5) raises my hackles.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd leverage a framework like Qt, because it is quite portable, it does abstract a lot of OS functionality (files, timing, threads, networking), and you get a decent, free IDE (Qt Creator) that is also portable and runs on Windows, OS X and any Unix flavor that runs Qt. It'd give you the lowest barrier to entry. Qt Creator can leverage the Visual Studio compiler and the CDB debugger if they are available.

You *do not* need to use OpenGL to use Qt, in fact you're not bound to any particular graphics subsystem. Qt only "uses" OpenGL in Qt 5 for the Qt Quick 2 graphics backend. It's not needed for Qt 4, nor for Qt Quick 1 (even in Qt 5!).

You can use any 2D or 3D framework you fancy to push images and other content to the screen. What Qt is good at is creating the kind of 2D imagery that is often needed in games - menus, configuration screens, HUDs, etc. There's a lot of controls and drawing primitives that Qt makes easy to leverage for your purposes.

Qt also lets you use a reasonably powerful model-view and networking frameworks, thus you'd be able to reasonably easily generate server or client lists that update in real time.

There'd need to be a small amount of shim code between Qt and DirectX, of course. On the output side, you typically end up with a `QImage` in Qt, and then use DirectX, SDL, OpenGL, etc. to push it to the screen. On the input side, you need to call `qApp->processEvents()` within your main game loop, and you will need to post user input events from DirectX etc. to Qt's event queue using `qApp->postEvent(...)`. This would be only needed if, say, DirectX main loop consumes all Windows messages and won't let standard winapi/win32 code (Qt's windows event dispatcher) see them. I haven't deal with DirectX much, so others feel free to chime in with details, of course.

Comment: I'm not aiming to write GUI applications. I'm more on the slant of games. I would certainly use Qt if I were aiming to write GUI's. 

Note: I added this on my main post under edit.

Comment: Qt is a general-purpose framework that doesn't force you to create a gui application. It has a rather sizable `core`, `network` and `sql` libraries that are used to create non-gui applications, such as servers. IIRC Qt is used in a large credit card approval processing system somewhere and most likely if you use credit or debit cards, some of your transactions went through that system.

Comment: Qt for example gives you a quite decent Unicode string class. Frequent code paths such as conversion between ASCII, Latin1 and internal UTF-16 representation [leverage SIMD instructions where possible](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/25/qstrings-and-unicode-optimising-qstringfromutf8/), for example.

Comment: Hm, would it actually be possible to implement Qt inside my game? For the GUI part of things, or is that out of the question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "implement Qt inside my game". Sure you can use Qt to paint on QImages that you can then use as textures/overlays for the HUD etc.

Comment: Sorry, I meant use Qt inside of my game. Just for the GUI side of things. But then I would be restricted to only be using OpenGL (since Qt does use OpenGL?), but I guess OpenGL is pretty much portable on every system. I guess it just makes it so that I don't have to write as much code and I can do things a lot quicker. And plus I wouldn't be able to use Direct3D for rendering, but then again I doubt I would have had to earlier.

Edit:
Sorry that I babble on about things, haha.

Comment: Ah I must have missed that part. Anyhow, thank you very much for your advice, time and the information you have given me. I really appreciate it. This will actually probably save me a lot of time and hassles :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CMake is a good choice. You can learn to use it. Read a tutorial:
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html

But, if your targets are Linux and Windows only. It is probably OK, in your case (small/average first multi-platform project), to maintain 2 separate build systems.

- On Linux, Use Make. It is standard and has a very good reference manual:
  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
- On Windows. Use your IDE project file, be it Visual, DevC++ or other. That is the simplest way to go.

Most important, make it easy to test your library/software on different platforms. Install a virtual machine on your desktop. Or at least compile your library into Cygwin.

Once you are here come back on stackoverflow and we will help !